# How to send funds to a Governor treasury?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I am working on creating a DAO using the ERC20Votes and Governor contracts. I created the governor using the wizard, however I don't see any function for adding funds to the Governor treasury. I imagine this is necessary so that the token holders can vote for proposals that allocate funds from the treasury. Is this function already implemented or do I have to implement it myself?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/Governor.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorSettings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorCountingSimple.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotes.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotesQuorumFraction.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorTimelockControl.sol";

contract MyGovernor is Governor, GovernorSettings, GovernorCountingSimple, GovernorVotes, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction, GovernorTimelockControl {
    constructor(ERC20Votes _token, TimelockController _timelock)
        Governor("MyGovernor")
        GovernorSettings(1 /* 1 block */, 45818 /* 1 week */, 0)
        GovernorVotes(_token)
        GovernorVotesQuorumFraction(4)
        GovernorTimelockControl(_timelock)
    {}

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function votingDelay()
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingDelay();
    }

    function votingPeriod()
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingPeriod();
    }

    function quorum(uint256 blockNumber)
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.quorum(blockNumber);
    }

    function getVotes(address account, uint256 blockNumber)
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorVotes)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.getVotes(account, blockNumber);
    }

    function state(uint256 proposalId)
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (ProposalState)
    {
        return super.state(proposalId);
    }

    function propose(address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, string memory description)
        public
        override(Governor, IGovernor)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.propose(targets, values, calldatas, description);
    }

    function proposalThreshold()
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.proposalThreshold();
    }

    function _execute(uint256 proposalId, address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
    {
        super._execute(proposalId, targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _cancel(address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super._cancel(targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _executor()
        internal
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (address)
    {
        return super._executor();
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify your question? If you want to send an ERC20 to the Governance contract, you can do that without any code on the contract side with something like: `ERCToken.transfer(governanceContract.address, amount`

If you're trying to send native ETH, the receive method is implemented here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/25eeb80b188876b951e592a810785173495097fc/contracts/governance/Governor.sol#L62

If, on the other hand, you're trying to tie a specific ERC20 as the governance token for the governance contract, I believe you need to implement that yourself per this comment: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/25eeb80b188876b951e592a810785173495097fc/contracts/governance/utils/Votes.sol#L24

Comment: Yes I was wondering about either sending the ERC20 token (that I already deployed as the governance token) or native ETH to the governance contract. I think that is the only way to allow the holders to vote on proposals to spend it right?